# Is it possible to make different codes work on different tab using "Script Editor" in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am just working on a spreadsheet with data validation based on different condition (dependent data validation). We have just created and the script has been updated for the same. However, I am unable to make it work on different tabs(scripts to work for each tabs). Now I have updated the script for three different tabs, however, my script is working only for the last one that I have created in the name of "Arvind". Could you please help me in making the sheet work for different tabs with different names using the same script in the apps? Copied (Authorized) script as below for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYmbsQYiS33aAoOqdRCa9rGVESXj5duC3V02fp1nxk0/edit#gid=820561296

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        allValues, list,

        /*'easy to change' variables*/
        sheet = 'James Main Sheet',
        sheetWithLists = 'Type of Request',
        rangeWithLists = 'B1:H', //assuming the first row to be the header row
        colValidation = 2, //the column with the 'first' validation
        secondValidationOffset = 1; //the offset from the above column / the column with the 'second' validation

    /*check conditions*/
    if (sh.getName() !== sheet || e.range.columnStart !== colValidation || e.range.rowStart < 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;

    /*get all values from the sheet with the lists (cached after the first run)*/
    allValues = getFromCache_(sheetWithLists, rangeWithLists)

    /*get the correct list(column) and remove the header*/
    list = allValues.map(function (v, i) {
        return v[allValues[0].indexOf(e.value)]
    }).splice(1);

    /*set the validation in offset column*/
    e.range.offset(0, secondValidationOffset)
        .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
            .requireValueInList(list)
            .build());
}

/*Using caching mechanism to limit the calls to the sheet with the lists --> faster execution*/
function getFromCache_(sheetName, range) {

    var key = 'DD_' + sheetName,
        c = CacheService.getPublicCache(),
        d,
        t = c.get(key);
    if (t) {
        d = JSON.parse(t);
    } else {
        d = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
            .getSheetByName(sheetName)
            .getRange(range)
            .getValues();
        c.put(key, JSON.stringify(d));
    }
    return d;
}

//Script courtesy of Top Contributor Jean-Pierre Verhulst
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is only working in the last sheet is because of following 2 lines of code:

```
sheet = 'James Main Sheet'
... 
if (sh.getName() !== sheet || e.range.columnStart !== colValidation || e.range.rowStart < 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
```

The sheet variable is set to `James Main sheet` hence will work only on that sheet. The if functions looks to see if you are sheet you are editing is that sheet via this `sh.getName() !== sheet` if the names do not match the function is terminated using `return`.

Assuming you what this code to work on all sheets except `Type of request` sheet. You modify the code to this

```
sheet = 'Type of request'
... 
if (sh.getName() == sheet || e.range.columnStart !== colValidation || e.range.rowStart < 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
```

Final code will look like this:

```
function onEdit(e) { var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet(), allValues, list,

    /*'easy to change' variables*/
    sheet = 'Type of request',
    sheetWithLists = 'Type of Request',
    rangeWithLists = 'B1:H', //assuming the first row to be the header row
    colValidation = 2, //the column with the 'first' validation
    secondValidationOffset = 1; //the offset from the above column / the column with the 'second' validation

/*check conditions, exit function if the sheet name is 'type of request'*/
if (sh.getName() == sheet || e.range.columnStart !== colValidation || e.range.rowStart < 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return; 

/*get all values from the sheet with the lists (cached after the first run)*/
allValues = getFromCache_(sheetWithLists, rangeWithLists)

/*get the correct list(column) and remove the header*/
list = allValues.map(function (v, i) {
    return v[allValues[0].indexOf(e.value)]
}).splice(1);

/*set the validation in offset column*/
e.range.offset(0, secondValidationOffset)
    .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInList(list)
        .build());
}

/Using caching mechanism to limit the calls to the sheet with the lists --> faster execution/ function getFromCache_(sheetName, range) {

var key = 'DD_' + sheetName,
    c = CacheService.getPublicCache(),
    d,
    t = c.get(key);
if (t) {
    d = JSON.parse(t);
} else {
    d = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName(sheetName)
        .getRange(range)
        .getValues();
    c.put(key, JSON.stringify(d));
}
return d;
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much, Jack. It worked perfectly.  I m happy to see the sheet work on the expected condition within a day. I just created a new sheet and used your code and made every possible thing to make it work perfectly. All of the tabs are loading fine without any issues. Thank you once again for you help.

Comment: If this is solves your problem please accept this as a answer

Comment: Yes! It solved by the problem... How to accept this as an answer??

Comment: This will cover the basics of [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answers. In short "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"